# how is payment integration in Magento 2.3 different from Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-gateway, magento2.3

I need to convert my module from 1.9 to 2.3. 
Can anyone explain what are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Although, I have not tried it before, but there are some scripts available which claim that they can convert Magento 1.x modules to Magento 2.x modules.

Below are some reference links:

https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2

Since folder structure and coding pattern are totally different between Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x, one can not use Magento 1.x modules directly into Magento 2.x, but there is an official code migration tool which can help the developers to migrate theirs modules and design themes:

https://github.com/magento/code-migration

But the tools is for experienced developers only.